# Add modified date on search result of SharePoint 2013

Tags: search-results, display-template

I need the modified date of the item when search results displayed. kindly help me doing this. I referred some MSDN article, where they have mentioned editing HTML file of display template on "Design galleries" under site settings.
:- kindly help me out with HTML code to get it or any other step to do it.

[image: My requirement]
[image: Web part settings details]

**HTML file of my Item display template.**
 

Default Item

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
<mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays the default result item template.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#</mso:TargetControlType>
<mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
<mso:ManagedPropertyMapping msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;,&#39;Path&#39;:&#39;Path&#39;,&#39;Description&#39;:&#39;Description&#39;,&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;:&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;,&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;:&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;,&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;:&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;,&#39;DocId&#39;:&#39;DocId&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;,&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;,&#39;FileExtension&#39;:&#39;FileExtension&#39;,&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;:&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;,&#39;ParentLink&#39;:&#39;ParentLink&#39;,&#39;FileType&#39;:&#39;FileType&#39;,&#39;IsContainer&#39;:&#39;IsContainer&#39;,&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;:&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;,&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;:&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
<mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://itg-proposalweb.ext.hp.com/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Search/Item_Default.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">TKEDMPT7QM5T-128-240</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">c172ec75-6a31-49db-a278-d7fc3ce31c84</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">https://itg-proposalweb.ext.hp.com/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=TKEDMPT7QM5T-128-240, TKEDMPT7QM5T-128-240</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Item_Default">
<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
            var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
            var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
            var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
            var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
            $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
            if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
            }
            ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
            ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data-displaytemplate="DefaultItem" class="ms-srch-item" onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">
                _#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>
            </div>
<!--#_ 
        } 
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the output what i expected now i am getting Date Modified in the search result. 
I edited "Result type" in setting and created custom word item display template by adding HTML code to that file.

To Get Date&Time:
var modifiedDate= ctx.CurrentItem.LastModifiedTime
This will get the date and time in UTC format like Sat Jul 19 2014 11:51:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

If you want only Date, use $getItemValue() as
var modifiedDate= $getItemValue(ctx, "LastModifiedTime")
This will give Time like Saturday, July 19, 2014

Now once you have both the values, you can display in any div or create your own html element and add it below the ctx.RenderBody(ctx) call.

Modified by,_#= author =#_  On _#= modifiedDate=#_

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
 <mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden>
 <mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Displays the default result 
  item template.</mso:MasterPageDescription>
 <mso:ContentTypeId 
 msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106603
 </mso:ContentTypeId>
 <mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;# 
 </mso:TargetControlType>
 <mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated>
 <mso:ManagedPropertyMapping 
 msdt:dt="string">&#39;Title&#39;:&#39;Title&#39;,&#39;Path&#39;:&#39
 ;Path&#39;,&#39;Description&#39;:&#39;Description&#39;,&#39;EditorOWSUSER
 &#39;:&#39;EditorOWSUSER&#39;,&#39;LastModifiedTime&#39;:&#39;
 LastModifiedTime&#39;,&#39;CollapsingStatus&#39;:&#39;
 CollapsingStatus&#39;,&#39;DocId&#39;:&#39;DocId&#39;,&#39;
 HitHighlightedSummary&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedSummary&#39;,&#39;
 HitHighlightedProperties&#39;:&#39;HitHighlightedProperties&#39;,&#39;
 FileExtension&#39;:&#39;FileExtension&#39;,&#39;ViewsLifeTime&#39;:&#39;
 ViewsLifeTime&#39;,&#39;ParentLink&#39;:&#39;ParentLink&#39;,&#39;
 FileType&#39;:&#39;FileType&#39;,&#39;IsContainer&#39;:&#39;
 IsContainer&#39;,&#39;SecondaryFileExtension&#39;:&#39;
 SecondaryFileExtension&#39;,&#39;DisplayAuthor&#39;:&#39;
 DisplayAuthor&#39;</mso:ManagedPropertyMapping>
 <mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded 
 msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded>
 <mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://itg- 
proposalweb.ext.hp.com/_catalogs/masterpage/Display%20Templates/Search/
Item_Default.html, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">TKEDMPT7QM5T-128-240</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">c172ec75-6a31-49db-a278- 
d7fc3ce31c84</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">https://itg- 
proposalweb.ext.hp.com/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=TKEDMPT7QM5T-128-240, 
TKEDMPT7QM5T-128-240</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="Item_Default">
<!--#_ 
  if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
    var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
    var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
    var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
    var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display 
    Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
    $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
    if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
        ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
    }
    ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = 
    Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
    ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = 
    Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
    <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data- 
    displaytemplate="DefaultItem" class="ms-srch-item" onmouseover="_#= 
    ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= 
    ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">
        _#=ctx.RenderBody(ctx)=#_
        <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover- 
        outerContainer"></div>
    </div>
 <!--#_ 
   }
 if (ctx.CurrentItem.LastModifiedTime) {
        var lastModifiedTime = ctx.CurrentItem.LastModifiedTime;
        var lastModifiedMonth = lastModifiedTime.getMonth() + 1;
        if(lastModifiedMonth < 10) {lastModifiedMonth = "0" + 
        lastModifiedMonth}
        var lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedTime.getDate();
        if(lastModifiedDate < 10) {lastModifiedDate = "0" + 
        lastModifiedDate}
        var lastModifiedTimeHtml = lastModifiedTime.getFullYear() + "-" 
        + lastModifiedMonth + "-" + lastModifiedDate;
  _#-->
  <div class="srch-subTitle">
  <h3 class="ms-soften" style="font-size:14px; display:inline">_#= 
  $htmlEncode(Srch.Res.hp_LastModified) =#_</h3><span class="ms-srch- 
  ellipsis">: _#= $htmlEncode(lastModifiedTimeHtml) =#_</span>
  </div>
 <!--#_ 
    }
 _#-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Chetan I hope this answer help you to achive your goal

Comment: I edited my file with your code. But when I select this edited or any other display template from web part setting my page will be loading when I try to click apply button

Comment: @Chetan You can do this in a different way, in site settings go to **Searh Result Types** and there you can select the display template you want to link to your result type

Comment: I did as you said, but my changes are not reflecting on the search page.Then saw that in the above-attached web part settings screenshot we selected "Use result type to display items" radio button. So I need to change that result type file right?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that'

Comment: you want to use this display template on Word Refinement

Comment: but why my changes are not reflecting.what all changes I should do now if we consider this as a fresh issue. kindly refer to web part setting that is currently we are using

Comment: ok add me in your skype meladfrancis@hotmail.com so we go through it together

Comment: fine will ping you through skype

Comment: I got my output as you directed I changed the HTML code in word display template. Thank you.

Comment: Great job, you did it